# Get data from both side of a query

Tags: mysql

I've the following query but if I search a data contained in table_b or table_c or table_d I don't get result can you pls. explain me why and correct the problem?

```
SELECT c.contratto,nominativo, email_pers,dt_ch_conto 
FROM clienti AS c
LEFT JOIN table_b AS s ON (c.contratto=s.contratto)
LEFT JOIN table_c AS r ON (c.contratto=r.contratto)
LEFT JOIN table_d AS n ON (c.contratto=n.contratto)
WHERE (nominativo LIKE '%$stringa%' OR c.contratto LIKE '%$stringa%' OR c.email_pers LIKE '%$stringa%') 
OR ((s.login LIKE '%$stringa%' AND s.attivo='SI')  
OR (r.login LIKE '%$stringa%' AND r.attivo='SI') 
OR (n.login LIKE '%$stringa%' AND n.attivo='SI'))  
AND ((dt_ch_conto is null) AND (dt_ch_conto=0) AND (dt_ch_conto='')) GROUP BY c.contratto LIMIT 15
```

Comment: y not `c.nominativo, c.email_pers,c.dt_ch_conto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE clause consists of

```
(or-expression) AND (and-expression)
```

with the and-expression

```
 ((dt_ch_conto is null) AND (dt_ch_conto=0) AND (dt_ch_conto=''))
```

This expression can't be true, because dt_ch_conto can't have at the same time the values

```
NULL,
0,
''
```

So you have

```
(expression) AND False
```

what evaluates to

```
WHERE false
```

for every row. I can't be certain but probably you want in the second expression

```
((dt_ch_conto is null) OR (dt_ch_conto=0) OR (dt_ch_conto=''))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but if I search a data contained on clienti i get result, if i search on table_b I get nothing